# Sublime Text Keep Executing Python.exe After Build is Cancelled

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext

Greetings dear community,

I am currently using Sublime Text 2 (Unregistered) as my coding agent. And there is a strange behavior i noticed lately. When i am running a code in sublime text(Through build, with CTRL-B), if a code needs long time to run, like an infinite loop, I try to cancel the build(I specified CTRL-SHIFT-B to cancel build), sublime text shows me a message that build is cancelled

```
[Cancelled]
```

like so. In regular command line this means python program is no longer running. As I think it should be the same in sublime text, however, it is not. As longer i keep trying to cancel than build again, more and more python.exe keeps showing in the task manager. I can have like 10 python.exe running behind if I don't end process manually through task manager. Can somebody explain this behavior to me please ? And the reason behind it, can I prevent it ?

By the way, I tested the Python IDLE, and command prompt before asking so i could provide more information

Python IDLE shows same behavior and keeps python exe's running after cancelling.

Command prompt stops the process with no problem.

I am using python2 in a windows 8.1 system.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please upgrade to [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3) and see if the problem repeats itself.

Comment: Problem also occurs in python IDLE as I mentioned, but will try.